# Animated transitions in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation

I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Here's the problem:
Consider a (Control|Data)Template with a Trigger that switches visibility of some inner UI elements. E.g. show a TextBlock when IsReadOnly==true and show a TextBox when IsReadOnly==false.

Everything is perfect if you do this without animation - one or two setters would do the job. But what if you want a fancy animation? Then you would specify which animations to start in EnterActions and ExitActions.

But the problem is what exactly the animations should do? Modifying width/height seems really ugly, because fixed sizes in WPF are almost always a wrong way to go and also it's absolutely unflexible.

So far, the best I've come up with is modifying MaxHeight/MaxWidth to some extent, this gives just a little more flexibility but still seems brutal.

**How do you tell WPF to animate Width/Height of an element from 0 to "as much as needed"?**

**UPD:** Currently I do animate Opacity and RenderTransform, and it works. It's just that sometimes I'd like to see animations where elements slide around without transformation. This is not a critical question, but a quite interesting one for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most animations, you should use either render transform or opacity or both. I almost never use anything else.

To make your text "Grow", animate Scale of a render transform. Do not forget about the center point.

Use Expression Blend to quickly get to the desired effect.

Comment: yes, i use RenderTransform animations too, but sometimes i wouldn't like to see animation of controls being "compressed" and "decompressed"...

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Transitionals Framework](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/releases/view/15792). It might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using transition effects from Blend SDK. A good explanation of building custom TransitionControl which internally uses pixel shader can be found [here](http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2011/11/wpf-transitions-using-pixel-shaders-and.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to animate the opacity : make the TextBlock fade out while the TextBox fades in, and vice versa.